# Azure Cognitive Search, how to iterate over facets to bypass 100K limit

Tags: azure, loops, search, facet

I understand the limitation of the API with the 100K limit, and MS's site says as a work around "you can work around this limitation by adding code to iterate over, and filter on, a facet with less that 100K documents per facet value."

I'm using the "Back up and restore an Azure Cognitive Search index" sample solution provided by MS. (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-dotnet-samples)

But can some when tell me where or how I implement this "iterate loop" on a facet" The facetable field I'm trying to use is "tributekey" but I don't know where to place the code in the below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// This is a prototype tool that allows for extraction of data from a search index
// Since this tool is still under development, it should not be used for production usage

using Azure;
using Azure.Search.Documents;
using Azure.Search.Documents.Indexes;
using Azure.Search.Documents.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AzureSearchBackupRestore
{
    class Program
    {

        private static string SourceSearchServiceName;
        private static string SourceAdminKey;
        private static string SourceIndexName;
        private static string TargetSearchServiceName;
        private static string TargetAdminKey;
        private static string TargetIndexName;
        private static string BackupDirectory;

        private static SearchIndexClient SourceIndexClient;
        private static SearchClient SourceSearchClient;
        private static SearchIndexClient TargetIndexClient;
        private static SearchClient TargetSearchClient;

        private static int MaxBatchSize = 500;          // JSON files will contain this many documents / file and can be up to 1000
        private static int ParallelizedJobs = 10;       // Output content in parallel jobs

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Get source and target search service info and index names from appsettings.json file
            //Set up source and target search service clients
            ConfigurationSetup();

            //Backup the source index
            Console.WriteLine("\nSTART INDEX BACKUP");
            BackupIndexAndDocuments();

            //Recreate and import content to target index
           //Console.WriteLine("\nSTART INDEX RESTORE");
           //DeleteIndex();
           //CreateTargetIndex();
           //ImportFromJSON();
           //Console.WriteLine("\r\n  Waiting 10 seconds for target to index content...");
           //Console.WriteLine("  NOTE: For really large indexes it may take longer to index all content.\r\n");
           //Thread.Sleep(10000);
           //
           //// Validate all content is in target index
           //int sourceCount = GetCurrentDocCount(SourceSearchClient);
           //int targetCount = GetCurrentDocCount(TargetSearchClient);
           //Console.WriteLine("\nSAFEGUARD CHECK: Source and target index counts should match");
           //Console.WriteLine(" Source index contains {0} docs", sourceCount);
           //Console.WriteLine(" Target index contains {0} docs\r\n", targetCount);
           //
           //Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
           //Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void ConfigurationSetup()
        {

            IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();

            SourceSearchServiceName = configuration["SourceSearchServiceName"];
            SourceAdminKey = configuration["SourceAdminKey"];
            SourceIndexName = configuration["SourceIndexName"];
            TargetSearchServiceName = configuration["TargetSearchServiceName"];
            TargetAdminKey = configuration["TargetAdminKey"];
            TargetIndexName = configuration["TargetIndexName"];
            BackupDirectory = configuration["BackupDirectory"];

            Console.WriteLine("CONFIGURATION:");
            Console.WriteLine("\n  Source service and index {0}, {1}", SourceSearchServiceName, SourceIndexName);
            Console.WriteLine("\n  Target service and index: {0}, {1}", TargetSearchServiceName, TargetIndexName);
            Console.WriteLine("\n  Backup directory: " + BackupDirectory);

            SourceIndexClient = new SearchIndexClient(new Uri("https://" + SourceSearchServiceName + ".search.windows.net"), new AzureKeyCredential(SourceAdminKey));
            SourceSearchClient = SourceIndexClient.GetSearchClient(SourceIndexName);

       
           // TargetIndexClient = new SearchIndexClient(new Uri($"https://" + TargetSearchServiceName + ".search.windows.net"), new AzureKeyCredential(TargetAdminKey));
           // TargetSearchClient = TargetIndexClient.GetSearchClient(TargetIndexName);
       }

        static void BackupIndexAndDocuments()
        {
            // Backup the index schema to the specified backup directory
            Console.WriteLine("\n  Backing up source index schema to {0}\r\n", BackupDirectory + "\\" + SourceIndexName + ".schema");

            File.WriteAllText(BackupDirectory + "\\" + SourceIndexName + ".schema", GetIndexSchema());

            // Extract the content to JSON files 
            int SourceDocCount = GetCurrentDocCount(SourceSearchClient);
            WriteIndexDocuments(SourceDocCount);     // Output content from index to json files
        }

        static void WriteIndexDocuments(int CurrentDocCount)
        {
            // Write document files in batches (per MaxBatchSize) in parallel
            string IDFieldName = GetIDFieldName();
            int FileCounter = 0;
            for (int batch = 0; batch <= (CurrentDocCount / MaxBatchSize); batch += ParallelizedJobs)
            {

                List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
                for (int job = 0; job < ParallelizedJobs; job++)
                {
                    FileCounter++;
                    int fileCounter = FileCounter;
                    if ((fileCounter - 1) * MaxBatchSize < CurrentDocCount)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("  Backing up source documents to {0} - (batch size = {1})", BackupDirectory + "\\" + SourceIndexName + fileCounter + ".json", MaxBatchSize);

                        tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                            ExportToJSON((fileCounter - 1) * MaxBatchSize, IDFieldName, BackupDirectory + "\\" + SourceIndexName + fileCounter + ".json")
                        ));
                    }

                }
                Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());  // Wait for all the stored procs in the group to complete
            }

            return;
        }

        static void ExportToJSON(int Skip, string IDFieldName, string FileName)
        {
            // Extract all the documents from the selected index to JSON files in batches of 500 docs / file
            string json = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                SearchOptions options = new SearchOptions()
                {
                    SearchMode = SearchMode.All,
                    Size = MaxBatchSize,
                    Skip = Skip,
                     
                  // ,IncludeTotalCount = true
                  // ,Filter = Azure.Search.Documents.SearchFilter.Create('%24top=2&%24skip=0&%24orderby=tributeId%20asc')
                  //,Filter = String.Format("&search=*&%24top=2&%24skip=0&%24orderby=tributeId%20asc")
                  //,Filter = "%24top=2&%24skip=0&%24orderby=tributeId%20asc"
                  //,Filter = "tributeKey eq '5'"




                };

                SearchResults<SearchDocument> response = SourceSearchClient.Search<SearchDocument>("*", options);

                foreach (var doc in response.GetResults())
                {
                    json += JsonSerializer.Serialize(doc.Document) + ",";
                    json = json.Replace("\"Latitude\":", "\"type\": \"Point\", \"coordinates\": [");
                    json = json.Replace("\"Longitude\":", "");
                    json = json.Replace(",\"IsEmpty\":false,\"Z\":null,\"M\":null,\"CoordinateSystem\":{\"EpsgId\":4326,\"Id\":\"4326\",\"Name\":\"WGS84\"}", "]");
                    json += "\r\n";
                }

                // Output the formatted content to a file
                json = json.Substring(0, json.Length - 3); // remove trailing comma
                File.WriteAllText(FileName, "{\"value\": [");
                File.AppendAllText(FileName, json);
                File.AppendAllText(FileName, "]}");
                Console.WriteLine("  Total documents: {0}", response.GetResults().Count().ToString());
                json = string.Empty;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }

        static string GetIDFieldName()
        {
            // Find the id field of this index
            string IDFieldName = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                var schema = SourceIndexClient.GetIndex(SourceIndexName);
                foreach (var field in schema.Value.Fields)
                {
                    if (field.IsKey == true)
                    {
                        IDFieldName = Convert.ToString(field.Name);
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message.ToString());
            }

            return IDFieldName;
        }

        static string GetIndexSchema()
        {

            // Extract the schema for this index
            // We use REST here because we can take the response as-is

            Uri ServiceUri = new Uri("https://" + SourceSearchServiceName + ".search.windows.net");
            HttpClient HttpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("api-key", SourceAdminKey);

            string Schema = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri(ServiceUri, "/indexes/" + SourceIndexName);
                HttpResponseMessage response = AzureSearchHelper.SendSearchRequest(HttpClient, HttpMethod.Get, uri);
                AzureSearchHelper.EnsureSuccessfulSearchResponse(response);
                Schema = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message.ToString());
            }

            return Schema;
        }

        private static bool DeleteIndex()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n  Delete target index {0} in {1} search service, if it exists", TargetIndexName, TargetSearchServiceName);
            // Delete the index if it exists
            try
            {
                TargetIndexClient.DeleteIndex(TargetIndexName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  Error deleting index: {0}\r\n", ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("  Did you remember to set your SearchServiceName and SearchServiceApiKey?\r\n");
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        static void CreateTargetIndex()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n  Create target index {0} in {1} search service", TargetIndexName, TargetSearchServiceName);
            // Use the schema file to create a copy of this index
            // I like using REST here since I can just take the response as-is

            string json = File.ReadAllText(BackupDirectory + "\\" + SourceIndexName + ".schema");

            // Do some cleaning of this file to change index name, etc
            json = "{" + json.Substring(json.IndexOf("\"name\""));
            int indexOfIndexName = json.IndexOf("\"", json.IndexOf("name\"") + 5) + 1;
            int indexOfEndOfIndexName = json.IndexOf("\"", indexOfIndexName);
            json = json.Substring(0, indexOfIndexName) + TargetIndexName + json.Substring(indexOfEndOfIndexName);

            Uri ServiceUri = new Uri("https://" + TargetSearchServiceName + ".search.windows.net");
            HttpClient HttpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("api-key", TargetAdminKey);

            try
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri(ServiceUri, "/indexes");
                HttpResponseMessage response = AzureSearchHelper.SendSearchRequest(HttpClient, HttpMethod.Post, uri, json);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  Error: {0}", ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }

        static int GetCurrentDocCount(SearchClient searchClient)
        {
            // Get the current doc count of the specified index
            try
            {
                SearchOptions options = new SearchOptions()
                {
                    SearchMode = SearchMode.All,
                    IncludeTotalCount = true
                };

                SearchResults<Dictionary<string, object>> response = searchClient.Search<Dictionary<string, object>>("*", options);
                return Convert.ToInt32(response.TotalCount);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  Error: {0}", ex.Message.ToString());
            }

            return -1;
        }

        static void ImportFromJSON()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n  Upload index documents from saved JSON files");
            // Take JSON file and import this as-is to target index
            Uri ServiceUri = new Uri("https://" + TargetSearchServiceName + ".search.windows.net");
            HttpClient HttpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("api-key", TargetAdminKey);

            try
            {
                foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(BackupDirectory, SourceIndexName + "*.json"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("  -Uploading documents from file {0}", fileName);
                    string json = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
                    Uri uri = new Uri(ServiceUri, "/indexes/" + TargetIndexName + "/docs/index");
                    HttpResponseMessage response = AzureSearchHelper.SendSearchRequest(HttpClient, HttpMethod.Post, uri, json);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  Error: {0}", ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried adding a filter option in the ExportToJSON method but the request fails